# How to check Sensitivity of Mezzo Unit Tamper field and Mid value? Capybara rspec

Tags: rspec, capybara

Whether there is a list 'li' and all have the same classes. How to check Sensitivity of Mezzo Unit Tamper field and Mid value?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J6aKh.png)

Answer (score 0):

Pretty terrible markup to work with here but it's possible to write something like this, and then refactor into some helper methods elsewhere:

```
dropdown_container = find('label', text: 'Sensitivity of Mezzo Unit Tamper').find(:xpath, '..')
dropdown_container.should have_css('[aria-labelledby="select-label"]', text: 'Mid')
```

You could break it out into a helper somewhere like this:

```
def assert_dropdown_value(dropdown_label, val)
  dropdown_container = find('label', text: dropdown_label).find(:xpath, '..')
  dropdown_container.should have_css('[aria-labelledby="select-label"]', text: val)
end
```